# DDD, Aggregates and Repos

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have the following entities (example):

- `Book`
- `Author`

The `Book` entity is also an aggregate since it has related one or many `Author`s. Now I have a problem in how to fetch this aggregate from the repo. I have the following cases - and I also do need to take care of performance:

1. List all the `Book`s. No need to fetch `Author`s.
2. List all the `Books`s with `Author`s names. Obviously, we need to fetch the aggregate of `Book`s and related `Author`s.
3. List all the `Book`s with authors *count*. Similar to (2), except I do not want to fetch the `Author`s from the repo, just the count.

So how my repository should look like? Specific questions:

- Should we have method like `findBooks` and `findBooksWithAuthors` and `findBooksWithAuthorsCount`? But this would lead to crazy amount of methods, since our entities have many relationships between each other.
- Should we just have `findBooks` and then `loadAuthors` in `AuthorsRepo`, i.e. not doing the join, until we hit some performance issue, and then to refactor.
- Should I create some aggregate-value-objects, like: `BookAndAuthors` that describes relationships?

Please note that this example is trivial - and you have to know that our models are more rich and have more relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to fetch this kind of information to display on the UI ?,

I would encourage you to separate your read and write concerns, and keep your repository interface simple (similar to that of a collections interface).

Have a look at [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), it works very well with DDD and will help simplify your design to a great deal.

Once you get into CQRS, just keep in mind that CQRS **does not necessarily involve Event Sourcing**.

In your case I would recommend the simplest approach show in [this article](http://codeofrob.com/entries/cqrs-is-too-complicated.html), basically have a read service (can call it Finder), which fires SQL and gets you a DTO/Map of whatever you need for the UI.

Comment: Not only UI, the same code is used by other modules. Anyway, if I have understood it right, CQRS says that we have a separate model: the query model. You are suggesting to have a Finder with all kind of different methods for getting the data needed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested